# Is there a way to freeze the mob inside a spawner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The question is pretty straight forward. Is there a way to freeze the mob inside the spawner.

I think before 1.13 you could do `RequiredPlayerRange:0s`. Well, that's not working anymore (1.15) Is this a bug that has been patched?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
/data merge block (coords) {RequiredPlayerRange:0s}
```

This does not work with `/setblock` directly ([MC-80690](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-80690), so either `/data merge` command still needs to be run after a `/setblock` command or `MaxNearbyEntities` needs to be given as well, like this:

```
/setblock (coords) spawner{RequiredPlayerRange:0s,MaxNearbyEntities:0}
```

Comment: Please don't ask a new question in an answer, that's where the question field is for. I guess in this case it's just a bug that your tag gets ignored.

Comment: Also, note that doing this will completely disable the spawner. It only works as decoration then. The rotation is an indicator for it being able to spawn mobs.

Comment: Found the bug, added to the answer.